# Synapse Analytics Pyspark: TypeError: list object is not callable

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I need to create a new dataframe in Synapse Analytics using column names from another dataframe. The new dataframe will have just one column (column header:col_name and the columns names from the other dataframe are the cell values. Here's my code:

```
    df1= df.columns
    colName =[]
    for e in df1:
       list1 = [e]
       colName.append(list1)

    col=['col_name']

    df2=spark.createDataFrame(colName,col)
    display(df2)
```

The output table created look like below:
[image]
With the output dataframe, i can do the following count, display or withColumn command.

```
    df2.count()
    df2=df2.withColumn('index',lit(1))
```

But when i start doing the below filter command, i ended up with 'list' object not callable error message.

```
    display(df2.filter(col('col_name')=='dob'))
```

I am just wondering if anyone know what I am missing and how I can solve this.At the end i'd like to add a conditional column based on the value in the col_name column.

Comment: df2.filter("col_name = 'dob'")

Comment: use an IDE to avoid this kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two objects called `col`.
You did this :

```py
col=['col_name']
```

therefore, when you do this :

```
display(df2.filter(col('col_name')=='dob'))
```

you do not call `pyspark.sql.functions.col` anymore but `['col_name']`, hence, `TypeError: list object is not callable`.

Simply replace here :

```
# display(df2.filter(col('col_name')=='dob'))

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
display(df2.filter(F.col('col_name')=='dob'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for not only providing solution but also took the time explaining!